# Redis disconnects randomly when running on WSL but works perfectly when run on Linux server

Tags: node.js, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node-redis

I have node.js app that uses Redis as a cache among other things.

When my app is running on my Linux server it works great without any problems. But when I am running it locally on my windows machine through WSL it disconnects randomly but mostly when it idles.

it disconnects with this error:

```
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_info_cmd (C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\index.js:431:14)
    at C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\index.js:470:14
    at Object.callbackOrEmit [as callback_or_emit] (C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\lib\utils.js:89:9)
    at Command.callback (C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\lib\individualCommands.js:157:15)
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\index.js:309:29)
    at RedisClient.connection_gone (C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\index.js:602:14)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1307:12) {
  code: 'UNCERTAIN_STATE',
  command
}
```

And on rarer times with this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1139:16)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\index.js:341:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mynam\OneDrive\Desktop\nodeapp\node_modules\redis\index.js:222:14)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
}
```

Comment: Are you exceeding max-connection limits?

Comment: I tried increasing and decreasing the limit and noticed no difference whatsoever. I made sure that my app uses only one client and made sure of that using the CLIENT LIST redis-cli command. I also don't have any other app running on WSL other than another Redis instance that uses a different port (my node app runs directly on windows)